# Log Registered Services In Autofac DI

Tags: c#, autofac

I have a console application that uses Autofac. How can I access the registration information in the container programmatically?
Here is one sample output (It's for Unity framework):

```
Container has 14 Registrations:
+ IUnityContainer '[default]' Container
+ StorageAccount '[default]' ContainerControlled
+ IRetryPolicyFactory '[default]' ContainerControlled
+ IDataTable`1<SurveyRow> -> DataTable`1<SurveyRow> '[default]' Transient
+ IDataTable`1<QuestionRow> -> DataTable`1<QuestionRow> '[default]' Transient
+ IMessageQueue`1<SurveyAnswerStoredMessage> ->
MessageQueue`1<SurveyAnswerStoredMessage> 'Standard' Transient
+ IMessageQueue`1<SurveyAnswerStoredMessage> ->
MessageQueue`1<SurveyAnswerStoredMessage> 'Premium' Transient
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely query registered types using Autofac 's container.

**Example:**

> Note: I'm registering `ArrayList` for `IList` in sample code below.

```
containerBuilder.RegisterType<ArrayList>().As<IList>();

var container = containerBuilder.Build();
var componentRegistryRegistrations = container.ComponentRegistry.Registrations;
foreach (var componentRegistryRegistration in componentRegistryRegistrations) {
    Console.WriteLine(componentRegistryRegistration.Activator.LimitType);
}
```

Code will print on screen:

```
Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope
System.Collections.ArrayList
```

Comment: Thank you. as a side note you can also get implemented interfaces, life time etc... Console.WriteLine(componentRegistryRegistration.Lifetime);
          Console.WriteLine(componentRegistryRegistration.Services.First());